# MySQL delete all data from all tables after a specific date

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, wordpress

In a WordPress database I need to delete all data from all tables after a certain date.

I tried with this:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22';
```

with this:

```
DELETE * FROM table WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22';
```

with this:

```
DELETE * FROM * WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22';
```

with this:

```
DELETE * FROM TABLE `wp_aiowps_events`, `wp_aiowps_failed_logins`, `wp_aiowps_global_meta`, `wp_aiowps_login_activity`, `wp_aiowps_login_lockdown`, `wp_aiowps_permanent_block`, `wp_bwg_album`, `wp_bwg_album_gallery`, `wp_bwg_gallery`, `wp_bwg_image`, `wp_bwg_image_comment`, `wp_bwg_image_rate`, `wp_bwg_image_tag`, `wp_bwg_shortcode`, `wp_bwg_theme`, `wp_commentmeta`, `wp_comments`, `wp_easy_pie_contacts`, `wp_easy_pie_cs_entities`, `wp_easy_pie_cs_subscribers`, `wp_easy_pie_emails`, `wp_em_bookings`, `wp_em_events`, `wp_em_locations`, `wp_em_meta`, `wp_em_tickets`, `wp_em_tickets_bookings`, `wp_i_world_map`, `wp_layerslider`, `wp_links`, `wp_login_redirects`, `wp_namastecon_activities`, `wp_namastecon_comments`, `wp_namastecon_maillog`, `wp_namastecon_newsletters`, `wp_namastepro_badges`, `wp_namastepro_classes`, `wp_namastepro_class_managers`, `wp_namastepro_coupons`, `wp_namastepro_delayed_access`, `wp_namastepro_files`, `wp_namastepro_school_signups`, `wp_namastepro_school_students`, `wp_namastepro_shopcarts`, `wp_namastepro_student_classes`, `wp_namasterep_parents_students`, `wp_namaste_certificates`, `wp_namaste_history`, `wp_namaste_homeworks`, `wp_namaste_homework_notes`, `wp_namaste_payments`, `wp_namaste_student_certificates`, `wp_namaste_student_courses`, `wp_namaste_student_homeworks`, `wp_namaste_student_lessons`, `wp_namaste_student_modules`, `wp_namaste_visits`, `wp_options`, `wp_pieregister_code`, `wp_pms_member_subscriptions`, `wp_pms_payments`, `wp_pmxe_exports`, `wp_pmxe_google_cats`, `wp_pmxe_posts`, `wp_pmxe_templates`, `wp_postmeta`, `wp_posts`, `wp_red_file_manager`, `wp_rm_fields`, `wp_rm_forms`, `wp_rm_front_users`, `wp_rm_notes`, `wp_rm_paypal_fields`, `wp_rm_paypal_logs`, `wp_rm_stats`, `wp_rm_submissions`, `wp_rm_submission_fields`, `wp_sg_action`, `wp_sg_config`, `wp_sg_schedule`, `wp_statistics_exclusions`, `wp_statistics_historical`, `wp_statistics_pages`, `wp_statistics_search`, `wp_statistics_useronline`, `wp_statistics_visit`, `wp_statistics_visitor`, `wp_strong_views`, `wp_swpm_membership_meta_tbl`, `wp_swpm_membership_tbl`, `wp_swpm_members_tbl`, `wp_swpm_payments_tbl`, `wp_termmeta`, `wp_terms`, `wp_term_relationships`, `wp_term_taxonomy`, `wp_usermeta`, `wp_users`, `wp_wdslayer`, `wp_wdsslide`, `wp_wdsslider`, `wp_WP_SEO_404_links`, `wp_WP_SEO_Cache`, `wp_WP_SEO_Redirection`, `wp_WP_SEO_Redirection_LOG`, `wp_wysija_campaign`, `wp_wysija_campaign_list`, `wp_wysija_custom_field`, `wp_wysija_email`, `wp_wysija_email_user_stat`, `wp_wysija_email_user_url`, `wp_wysija_form`, `wp_wysija_list`, `wp_wysija_queue`, `wp_wysija_url`, `wp_wysija_url_mail`, `wp_wysija_user`, `wp_wysija_user_field`, `wp_wysija_user_history`, `wp_wysija_user_list` WHERE date > `2018-08-09 08:21:22`;
```

and other queries, but it doesn't work, I always get an error in SQL syntax.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178563/discussion-on-question-by-ste-yeu-mysql-delete-all-data-from-all-tables-after-a).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, I would do:

```
DELETE t FROM <table> t WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22';
```

Does this work? I know MySQL has flexibility in the `SELECT` syntax, but the `*`s just don't look right.

I can say that I'm pretty sure you don't want the last statement.  Multi-table delete is a nice feature, but do realize that most databases don't support it.  The most common use-cases are handled using cascading delete foreign key definitions.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<table> t WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22'' at line 1  :(

Comment: you should adjust the query to your table names replacing that <table> with the table name. Not just copy paste :-) @SteYeu

Comment: DELETE t FROM wp_users t WHERE date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22'; I tried with wp_posts too.

Comment: DELETE t FROM wp_posts WHERE post_date > '2018-08-09 08:21:22'; This works, but it's not possible to check every table manually. MySQL failed!